# Why are there no wild arcs in the plane?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, jordan-curves

On math.stackexchange [it was asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17062/is-there-essentially-only-1-jordan-arc-in-the-plane/17080#17080) whether all arcs in the plane are ambient-isotopic. I suggested that one could prove this by appealing to the Schönflies theorem, which you can do as long as you can extend your Jordan arc to a Jordan curve. That is, as long as you can extend an embedding of an interval to an embedding of a circle. However, I have to admit I don't readily see how to do this, and there are examples which show this is a subtle question. E.g. you can take an arc which spirals infinitely into a point. So my question is how one can show an embedding of an arc into $\mathbb R^2$ extends to an embedding of a circle into $\mathbb R^2$, or, failing that, if someone knows some other proof that all planar Jordan arcs are standard.

**Edit:** I want to highlight Bill Thurston's elegant answer (in a comment) to the question of whether you can extend an arc to a circle, even though I accepted his other answer using Caratheodory's theorem. Namely, assume your arc runs from $0$ to $\infty$ in $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$. Then take the pre-image under the double branched cover $z\mapsto z^2$. The original arc can be identified with one of its two preimages, while the other preimage fills it in to a circle. Then one can apply the Schönflies theorem.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One way to show all arcs are tame is to apply the Riemann mapping theorem to the complement of the arc on $S^2$. Caratheodory proved that whenever the complement of a simply-connected domain is locally connected, then the Riemann mapping extends to a continuous map of the disk to the plane. One half of the disk parametrizes the arc.

Another (related) method is to take the stereographic projection of the arc to a sphere
in $\mathbb E^3$, and form its convex hull.  If the interior of the ball is interpreted as the projective model for hyperbolic 3-space, then the boundary of the convex hull intersect the interior of the ball is a developable surface, i.e. its path metric (that is, distance between points is the minimum arc length of a path connecting them) is a complete metric locally isometric to the path-metric of the hyperbolic plane. Since it's simply-connected, it's globally isometric to the hyperbolic plane.  For reasons parallel to Caratheodory's the map extends continuously to a map of the closed disk (2-dimensional projective disk model of 
the hyperbolic plane, together with its circle at infinity) to the closed ball.

Comment: Is there a more direct relation between these two proofs, other than that they end in a similar way?  E.g., is there a correspondence or a relation between the conformal structure on the Jordan domain at infinity, and the hyperbolic structure on the pleated surface?

Comment: Dennis Sullivan found a simple way to construct a map from the boundary of the convex hull of a simply-connected domain to  the Poincaré metric on a simply-connected domain that has a bounded bi-Lipschitz constant.  David Epstein and Al Marden subsequently gave a very detailed and explicit construction, with an explicit constant. The natural conjecture (or at least a conjecture that is attributed to me) was that the best quasiconformal constant should be 2, but this was disproved: cf. Epstein, Marden and Markovic, Annals of Math 159 (2004) pp 305--336.

Answer (score 8):

By stereographic projection we can assume that the given Jordan arc
lies on a sphere, and that its two ends are at opposite poles, $N$
and $S$. Now project the arc onto a cylinder that touches the sphere
at the equator, so that $N$ and $S$ go to infinity on opposite ends
of the cylinder.

Unrolling the cylinder, we now have our arc on a strip of the plane,
with the ends of the arc at opposite ends of the strip. Now we can
inverse stereographically project the arc back onto the sphere, so
that *both* ends go to the point of projection. We now have a closed
Jordan  curve on the sphere, and we can apply the Schoenflies theorem.

**Edit.** Ryan Budney has pointed out the flaw in this argument, so I
withdraw it as it stands. Thanks for the amendment, Ryan.

Comment: How do you know the arc has ends? 

Comment: Based on the stackexchange question, I also assumed the arc is a compact one.

Comment: @Richard: in case your response is aimed at me, what I mean is in Stillwell's argument "our arc on a strip in the plane" is an arc in the universal cover of a twice punctured sphere -- this cover is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$, so showing the arc has endpoints on the boundary is a non-trivial problem (it's easy to construct ones that don't, even if they come from embedded intervals in $S^2$ via this construction). 

Comment: Oh, I think I see how one can tweak Stillwell's argument to make it work -- the lifted arc is in $(-1,1) \times \mathbb R$ which you could compactify to $[-1,1] \times [-\infty,\infty]$.  Crush $\{-1\}\times [-\infty,\infty]$ and $\{1\}\times [-\infty,\infty]$ to points and identify the quotient space with a compact disc -- the arc has ends in this quotient space. 

Comment: But a fixable flaw.  I like this argument.  

Comment: Actually, if the arc goes from $0$ to $\infty$ in $\hat{\mathbb C}$,
then just take the preimage under $z \mapsto z^2$: it's a circle.
It's nice, but it reduces the problem to another problem that
ab initio is just as hard, just better known.

Comment: @Bill: That's a clever way to do it!

Answer (score 4):

The desired result appears in M.H.A. Newman's classic book, *Elements of the Topology of Plane Sets of Points* (2nd ed., 1951), as Theorem 14.5 in Chapter VI, on pg. 164:

**Theorem 14.5:** *Every simple arc in $X^2$ is an arc of a simple closed curve in $X^2$.*

$X^2$ is Newman's notation for a space that is either the "open" plane, $R^2$, or the "closed" plane, $R^2 \cup \{\infty\}$.

**N.B.** The proof of Theorem 14.5 does not involve Schoenflies' Theorem. Also, Newman's definition of an arc is such that it has ends.