# A topological property of curves on the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Let $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a continuous **injective** map.

> Is it true that for any inner point $t\in (0,1)$ there exist an open neighborhood  $U$ of $\gamma(t)$ and a homeomorphism $f\colon U\tilde\to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(U\cap Im(\gamma))$ is equal to a line $\mathbb{R}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$?

A reference would be helpful.

Comment: Embed the image of $\gamma$ in a Jordan curve. Then the statement is obvious by Jordan-Schoenflies.

Comment: Here is a nice discussion about why every such $\gamma$ can be embedded in a Jordan curve: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57766/why-are-there-no-wild-arcs-in-the-plane