# "Thickening" an arc on a 2-manifold

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, topological-manifolds, jordan-curves

What is the argument for the fact that each arc in the interior of a 2-manifold can be "thickend" to obtain a 2-cell containing the arc in its interior and being disjoint from any preassigned compact set in the complement of the arc? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about, say, taking $V_{\delta/2}$, the set of points lying at most a distance $\delta/2$ away from the arc? Here $\delta > 0$ would be the distance between said arc and the preassigned compact set.

Comment: Are we assuming that the surface comes with a metric?

Comment: Also, taking a $\delta/2$--neighbourhood need not give a two-cell - you need to take the constant small enough to avoid the neighbourhood overlapping itself.

Comment: This is a delicate question if you want a real proof, and not "just" some handwaving about "oh, this follows from the Schoenflies theorem".

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $S$ is the surface, $\alpha$ is the arc, and $K$ is the compact set.

**Proof 1:** Find an arc $\alpha'$ so that $\gamma = \alpha \cup \alpha'$ is a Jordan curve (+).  The Jordan/Schoenflies [J/S] theorems provide an annulus (or Möbius) neighbourhood $A$ of $\gamma$ and a homeomorphism on $A$ making $\gamma$ "straight".  Shrink $A$ as needed to avoid $K$ and then use $A$ to find the desired two-cell.

**Proof 2:** Let $T$ be the double branched cover of $S$, branched over the two points of $\partial \alpha$.  Let $\beta$ and $\beta'$ be the two preimages of $\alpha$ in $T$.  So the union $\gamma = \beta \cup \beta'$ is a Jordan curve.  Apply [J/S] to find an annulus neighbourhood $A$ of $\gamma$.  Shrinking $A$ as needed, we may assume that it is disjoint from the preimage of $K$.  We further arrange matters so that $A$ is invariant under the deck transformation, as are two of its cutting arcs (meeting $\gamma$ in exactly the points $\partial \beta$). So the image of $A$ is the desired two-cell.

---

Of course, in Proof 1, sentence (+) is saying that endpoints of $\alpha$ are "accessible".  Showing such things is part of various proofs of [J/S]. The branched cover trick in Proof 2 is designed to avoid (+).  However, I'll guess that no proof can avoid using [J/S], or at least some of its "working parts".

Comment: Belevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57766/why-are-there-no-wild-arcs-in-the-plane

Comment: Yes, very relevant!  Also, I notice that I, sometime in the past voted, up that post and some of the answers... We should probably mark this question (and my answer) as a duplicate.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to write a comment, so I have to use the answer field to ask for the clarification for the first proof idea here.
@SamNead, could you please explain how one can apply the Jordan-Schoenflies to a surface? The statement of the theorem holds for now for a plane only. Then, it's also not so clear, why, for exmaple, a spiral arc $[0, 1] \to \mathbb{C}$, $t \mapsto (1 - t)e^{i \frac{1}{1 - t}}$, completed to a Jordan curve, has necesseraly an annulus neighbourhood. How exactly does it follow from the Jordan-Schoenflies? Finally, I've read the thread https

Comment: [Text continued from Palina Severyna's answer which was converted to a comment:] Finally, I've read the thread https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57766/why-are-there-no-wild-arcs-in-the-plane (you marked my question as duplicate to it) and couldn't 
understand in the argument of Bill Thurston, why the original arc can be identified with one of its two 
pre-images under the branched cover $z \to z^2$ of a sphere. What is a homeomorphism between them?
 
I also would like to remark that I may not assume that
the surface permits a triangulation.